# How can I remove diacritics (umlauts) from a String?

Tags: smalltalk, diacritics, pharo

How can I convert a string, such as `Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.` into `Prilis zlutoucky kun upel dabelske ody.`?

The source string is in Unicode, so in principle it should be possible to use normalization/decomposition to separate the umlaut.

Unfortunately I didn't see any library in Pharo (maybe Zinc hidden somewhere?) that would support either stripping umlauts or decomposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Diacriticals](http://www.smalltalkhub.com/#!/~hernan/Diacritics) package

Installation

```
Metacello new
    smalltalkhubUser: 'Pharo' project: 'MetaRepoForPharo50';
    configuration: 'Diacritics';
    version: #development;
    load.
```

Test

```
'Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy' asNonDiacritical.
 "'Prilis zlutoucky kun upel dabelske ody'"
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't, as far as I'm aware of and the algorithm's that can do this are quite costly, so you'll probably not want to use Smalltalk implementation of them. At the company I work, we created a VM plugin that makes the calls to libicu. That way we don't have to maintain a separate implementation and profit from native speed. See [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org) for reference.

Comment: Performance is not really an issue, as I am not going to apply it to massive data sets (I could use a translation table, but that's quite error prone). But what you are suggesting is to write a UFFI library for `libicu`?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Unfortunately, the plugin we wrote is for the Squeak 4 VM and I'm not sure how well it's portable to the new VM's.