# Smalltalk Unicode to ascii library

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is anyone aware of a smalltalk library for converting Unicode to ascii?

I'm hoping that it will be somewhat intelligent, i.e. remove diacritical
marks.  Non-ascii characters would either be removed or replace with
something like an underscore.  E.g.:

```
"ěščřžýáíé ❤"
```

would be converted to:

```
"escrzyaie _"
```

or:

```
"escrzyaie "
```

Thanks,
Alistair

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove diacritics (umlauts) from a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724281/how-can-i-remove-diacritics-umlauts-from-a-string)

Comment: I can certainly work with this, but it isn't quite what I'm looking for as it leaves other non-ascii characters in place, so there may still be a better answer.

Comment: But thanks for the pointer, I think this will be useful.

Comment: You talk about non-ASCII in one sentence, and non-printable in another. Can you clarify your exact specification? There are plenty of printable non-ASCII characters, and plenty of non-printable ASCII characters. For example, you say you want to replace non-printable characters with `_` or `<space>`, but then give `❤` as an example, which however is perfectly printable.

Comment: How faithful do you want the conversion to be? For example, what should my name be converted to? The "most correct" conversion would be "Joerg W Mittag". What should "Spaß" be converted to? Correct would be "Spass".  The correct transliteration of "Ĳsselmeer" is "IJsselmeer". And so on.

Comment: Are the strings normalized? If yes, in what form? If no, should it make a difference whether the string is, say, "Jörg" or "Jörg"?

Comment: You're right, I meant non-ascii, not non-printable.  In terms of what is "most correct" and normalisation, I'm not that fussy, the main purpose is to avoid problems with files being accessed on different machines, with Windows shares, etc.  Thanks.

Comment: What should happen if I have two files, one named `äo`, and one named `aö`? Should they both be mapped to the same name? And why do you think non-ASCII characters are bad, but have no problem with non-printable characters? Every Operating System, File System, and Network File System I know of has been Unicode-capable for at least a decade.

Comment: Any reason why you want to do this?

Comment: I just find filenames with diacritics in them a pain, difficult to search for, difficult to type in the name directly, some applications don't handle them well, etc.  Removing the diacritics and non-ascii characters leaves the filename still (mostly) meaningful, and gets around all the other issues.  The name clashes that Jorg mentioned haven't happened in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was clarified in the comments, my goal was to be able to convert
filenames containing non-ascii / non-printable characters into something
that would still be meaningful but only contain ascii characters.

Using the Diacritics library kindly pointed out by Peter I ended up
writing a small class that does the conversion.  If you're interested,
it is at:

https://github.com/akgrant43/AkgMiscellaneousUtilities/tree/master/mc/AKG-AsciiFilename.package

Thanks for all the assistance!